# MSSQL 2008 Single Statement with Join/Where Clause Satisfying Multiple Scenarios

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a handful of queries that need to have certain records filtered out. There are several different scenarios and I just can not seem to get a single query that will satisfy all of them.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78330/1/0)

I am trying to filter out customers with a current commitment, which due to table design is a record in the commitment table that has a null status and the CommitDate is greater than the current date.

The problem is that in certain scenarios the status of the commitment can be null but not be current. Also, there can be multiple commitment records tied to the same customer/agreement (multiple ones of these can have a null status but be "broken", which is an active commitment that is past the commitdate).

I also have to be able to include all customer/agreements that do not have any commitments tied to them.

At this point, I have gotten to where I am including some things but missing others. Then, when I include the missing ones, ones that were included are now missing.

I have the query that I have worked up and worked on and have no idea how many different things I have tried included with the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78330/1/0).

Altering table schema is not an option. These are tables that have been there before I started working with this (for over 15 years).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**** EDIT ****

[SQLFiddle With Testing Data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d8f51/3/0)

This covers all the scenarios that I can remember right now.

**** EDIT 2 ****

[New SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92ecc/1/0)

Comment: Please provide some test data which can describe all your situations.

Comment: I have been working on that for the last half hour. Since this is not "my" data/code, I do not feel right uploading the exact schemas so I am having to go through and manually figure out the data that needs to be inserted. I will edit the post when I get it done.

Comment: Added a new SQLFiddle link that has some test data. It returns two correct record, but ID # 4 should also be returned and it is not.

Comment: But your PEOPLE table contains no record for ID #4.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have been at the hospital for the last 10 days with my fiance and am trying to work remotely. I added the person for that particular agreement and re-ran the queries. As it is now, ID #1 should not be being returned. I will email my analyst and try to get a more complete data set and update tomorrow after an attempt at sleep.

Comment: I wonder how you have tagged Sql-server-2008, if your tables are 15 Years old!

Comment: We wish you good health and return to your workplace soon.